# Every time I write in a txt using the formatter the previous stuff writtern get deleted?How can avoid that?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.SecurityException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CreateTextFile {
    private Formatter output; //object used to output text to file
    private Order order;
    //enable user to open file 
    public void openFile()
    {
        try
        {
            output=new Formatter("src\\Orders.txt");//pen the file
        }//end try
        catch(SecurityException securityException)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You do not have the write access to this file.","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);//terminate the program
        }//end catch
        catch(FileNotFoundException filenotfoundexception)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error opening or creating file.","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);//terminate the program
        }//end catch
    }//end method openFile

    //add records to file
    public void addOrderstoSalesmen(String Description,String Date, double poso,int salesman,Employee currentEmployee)
    {
        try //output values to file
        {
            //retrieve data to be ouput
                    order=new Order(Description,Date,poso,salesman);
                   Salesman employee=(Salesman) currentEmployee;

                    employee.addOrder(order);
                    employee.setGrossSales(salesman);
                    output.format("%s,%s,%.0f\n",order.getDescription(),order.getDate(),order.getSales());
        }//end try
        catch(FormatterClosedException formatterclosedexception)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error writing to file.","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }//end catch
        catch(NoSuchElementException elementexception)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid input.Please try again.","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }//end catch

    }//end method addRecords
    public void CloseFile()
    {
        if(output!=null)
            output.close();

    }//end method closeFile

}//end class CreateTextFile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably opening, writing, closing the file and then repeating. Each time you open a file for writing, its contents are wiped clean. You can get around this by either:

1. Opening, writing, writing, ..., writing and only closing the file once you've done all the writing.
2. Open the file in append mode, so the old contents aren't erased.

Comment: @Paul I've never used `Formatter` to output to file. I usually use a `PrintWriter` wrapped around a `BufferedWriter`. You can specify append mode at the [`PrintWriter` level](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

Comment: I used BufferedWirter and fixed the problem.Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Using Formatter always *deletes* the file content when an existing file is being reopened as documented for the [constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.lang.String))

> … if the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; …

Use a BufferedWritter with a FileWritter (`append = true`) to construct the Formatter:

```
    new Formatter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/Orders.txt", true)));
```

*Note: it's a bit strange to have a program writing to the source directory*