# How to append to a file in java using formatter?

Tags: java, file-io, io, text-files

i have a simple problem. i use this code to add some records in text file using java but every time i run this program, the file is being created again. i wanna to append records without creating file again ?

```
   Formatter x = null;


    try{

    x = new Formatter("C:\\Users\\Hamada\\Downloads\\products.txt");

    }

    catch(Exception e)

    {

    //System.out.println("NO Database");

    }

    x.format("%d,%s,%s,%s,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",id, name, type, brand, quantity, day1, month1, year1, day2, month2, year2);

    x.close();
```

Comment: Do a search first before posting. A quick Google of "java formatter append" comes up with plenty of valid answers, including http://stackoverflow.com/a/4526103/998251

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add a FileStream to the Formatter such as the following and write the appendable to the Formatter.

```
FileWriter f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Hamada\\Downloads\\products.txt", true);
Formatter form = new Formatter(f);
```

Within the FileWriter pass the "true" parameter to append to the file and not overwrite the current contents.

Comment: where to add this code excatly sir. iam a java beginner

Comment: Add this within the try statement, you can declare the Formatter as "x" instead of "form" so that your other functions will work, I suggest also putting them into the try statement

Comment: sorry sir but it gives me error, can you write the whole code with your answer in order to understand please ??